# php 5.3.3 doesn't load mysql extension

Tags: php, mysql

I have a vps running php 5.3.3 and mysql 5.1.73

The problem is when I call the mysql_connect() it says:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in xyz.php on line 27`

I tried to view the loaded extensions by using the following snippet of code:

```
<?php // extensions_list.php 
$list = get_loaded_extensions(); 
$list2 = array_map('strtolower',$list); 
sort($list2); 
echo '<pre>'.print_r($list2,true).'</pre>'; 
?>
```

it generated the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apache2handler
    [1] => bz2
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => core
    [4] => ctype
    [5] => curl
    [6] => date
    [7] => ereg
    [8] => exif
    [9] => fileinfo
    [10] => filter
    [11] => ftp
    [12] => gettext
    [13] => gmp
    [14] => hash
    [15] => iconv
    [16] => json
    [17] => libxml
    [18] => openssl
    [19] => pcre
    [20] => phar
    [21] => reflection
    [22] => session
    [23] => shmop
    [24] => simplexml
    [25] => sockets
    [26] => spl
    [27] => standard
    [28] => tokenizer
    [29] => xml
    [30] => zip
    [31] => zlib
)
```

I tried adding adding the mysql extension by:

```
ini_set('extension=mysql.so',1);
```

but still no help.

Comment: I think newer versions of php doesn't support the `mysql* functions` anymore.

Comment: I don't think 5.3.3 counts as new... this sounds like RHEL/CentOS 5 or 6... if it is, did you do yum install php-mysql?  (rpm -qa | grep php)

Comment: Versions < PHP 5.5 aren't supported anymore and shouldn't be installed anymore. Upgrade your php installation.

Comment: What should I do then? @ShiguriAnemone'

Comment: @MalikJahanzaib use mysqli or pdo instead.